# javascript numbers assignment

Tags: javascript

i'm having some issues with the final two console.logs of my script. i'm supposed to have numbers output for both but i'm getting NAN

```
alert("Let's make a shopping list!");

let first = prompt("What is the first item?");

let firstCost = Number(prompt("What is the cost of " + first + "?"));

let firstAmount = Number(prompt("How many of " + first + " would you like?"));

let second = prompt("What is the second item?");

let secondCost = Number(prompt("What is the cost of " + second + "?"));

let secondAmount = Number(prompt("How many of " + second + " would you like?"));

let tax = parseInt(prompt("What is the sales tax for your state?"));

let firstTotal = parseFloat(firstCost * firstAmount);
let secondTotal = parseFloat(firstCost * firstAmount);
let subTotal = parseFloat(firstTotal + secondTotal);
let taxTotal = parseFloat(subTotal * tax);
let grandTotal = parseFloat(subTotal + taxTotal);

console.log(first + " " + firstCost + " " + firstAmount + " " + 
 firstTotal);
console.log(second + " " + secondCost + " " + secondAmount + " " + 
 secondTotal);
console.log("tax: " + taxTotal);
console.log("TOTAL: " + grandTotal);
```

I changed all of the `Number()` to `parseFloat()` but I'm not getting the outcome I'm looking for.

Comment: Tip: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) exist and can help clean up this code.

Comment: Hint: If you have numbers, you can do math on them without parsing. They're *already* numbers. Put the `parseFloat` down and step away!

Comment: @tadman, my prof wants us to so things in this really long way to start. im not allowed to use anything he hasn't taught us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Error 1. Copy/paste

This line of code is a mistake:

```
let secondTotal = parseFloat(firstCost * firstAmount);
```

You have copied-and-pasted, without changing "first" to "second".

#### Error 2. You haven't decided whether `tax` is a percentage or a decimal fraction

You are collecting an INTEGER, i.e. 5% tax will be stored as 5.

But you are using it as though it is a fraction (e.g. 5% represented as 0.05), by just multiplying it by subtotal.

#### Error 3. When entering data you are using 'cancel' to skip the tax value

This causes it to store NaN in the tax, and that messes up all output that depends on the tax.

#### Tip. To get answers quickly, get rid of all the code that is irrelevant, and make it runnable within Stack Overflow, using the "<>" icon.

That helps people help you.

```js
let firstCost = Number(prompt("What is the cost of first ?"));
let firstAmount = Number(prompt("How many of first would you like?"));
let secondCost = Number(prompt("What is the cost of second?"));
let secondAmount = Number(prompt("How many of second would you like?"));

// In this next line you are storing an integer (e.g. 5, for 5 percent) 
let tax = parseInt(prompt("What is the sales tax for your state?"));

let firstTotal = parseFloat(firstCost * firstAmount);


// This next line is a mistake
// let secondTotal = parseFloat(firstCost * firstAmount); 

// You meant this:
let secondTotal = parseFloat(secondCost * secondAmount);


let subTotal = parseFloat(firstTotal + secondTotal);

// But in this line you are treating it as though it is a decimal, e.g. 0.05 for 5 percent.
// let taxTotal = parseFloat(subTotal * tax);
// You probably meant this:
let taxTotal = parseFloat(subTotal * tax/100);

let grandTotal = parseFloat(subTotal + taxTotal);

console.log("tax: " + taxTotal);
console.log("TOTAL: " + grandTotal);
```